# C project O file still looking for Cpp file after removal during make

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, header-files

I am working on a C project and my objective is to remove some unwanted references from the project. So I changed my code and I do not need those references anymore.So I decided to remove files from my project folder just to see if it still works alright.

Now, As soon as I remove it and try to build again I see following error:

> *** No rule to make target `gnu_getopt.c', needed by`gnu_getopt.o'.  Stop

Funny thing is that I have removed both O file and C file manually and even I do search for them in the folder, I am not able to find them. I am not sure why(and where) it is still seeing the O file which is eventually looking for C file?

There is one thing that I noticed is that there is a folder called .DEPT and it has bunch of PO files. Even though I delete those files manually the GNU_getopt.PO file shows up there after a failed build.

On a side note, I am working in Cygwin environment I am not sure how helpful would that be?

Comment: Without seeing the Makefile, itäs pretty hard to say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the file from the `Makefile` check for a `SRCS =` or just grep the file for `gnu_getopt` and remove it.

Comment: I searhced make file for a reference to gnu_getopt but did not find anything?

Comment: @Californicated Check for Makefiles in sub folders or a file that lists all the source files for the project. You could just do it the hard way and grep all files in the project for it.

Comment: There is one thing that I noticed is that there is a folder called .DEPT and it has bunch of PO files. Even though I delete those files manually the GNU_getopt.PO file shows up there after a failed build.

Comment: @Californicated That's because there's a reference to `gnu_getopt.c` or `gnu_getopt.o` somewhere in the Makefile. It's probably trying to generate dependencies.

Comment: Ok let me see how can I grep in Cygwin. I think it is a good idea to grep the folder. I have dine the search in Visual studio but did not find anything. I think Cygwin grep wil lhelp

Comment: `grep -r "gnu_getopt" .`